# problem understanding the differences between curl and axios react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, axios

```
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: Token token-string-here' website_address
```

will give me a valid response with the data I need

I tried doing the following in componentDidMount function

```
  axios.get(
    url_string_value,
    {headers: {
        "Authorization" : token_string_value
      }
    }
  )
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
  })
```

But got a 500 error. Did I formate this correctly? Is there another problem I'm overlooking?

Comment: Not sure if `token_string_value` contains `Token ` prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks right. Check these two things.

1. URL has the right protocol (http vs https)
2. Header has right token.

`"Authorization" : token_string_value`

should be

`"Authorization" : Token token_string_value`

Also, `500` means the request has been received by the server and something went wrong. This most likely looks like header doesn't have the right format of token but the server is throwing `500` instead of `401`.

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake to make, but its working fine now